# Having Issues with handling Python dictionaries in Javascript flask templates

Tags: javascript, python, web, flask

So I am building a web application using flask that can track mutiple vehicles and provide updates. The python script helps gather all the data and puts them in a dictionary.

I am sending this dictionary over to the index.html with the javascript code within the HTML that initializes a map and places markers based on the coordinates received from python.

The issue I am having is this dictionary is not being parsed properly in js and as a result I get no data.

Right now I have the {{truck_dict}} placeholder to hold the dict object from python in the html.

PS. I am not the best at JS so dont judge XD

```
#Python Code
return render_template('pages/index.html', trucks = truck.driver_locator(truck.locations()))
#Even when I jsonify/json.dump the variable in the trucks object, nothing happens
```

```
#JS Code
var truck_dict = {{trucks | tojson}}
var i;
for (var key in truck_dict){
var value = truck_dict[key];
var geojson = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [{
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: value
         },
            properties: {
                  title: 'Mapbox',
                  description: '1303'
                  }
               }]
         };
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT of the python generated dict

```
{'1301': [43.1220307, -78.9352247], '1302': [42.3107737, -77.2519131], '1304': [40.3809016, -74.5665863], '1305': [40.2453049, -74.5707928], '1303': [39.6435448, -75.9325289]}
```

Comment: We aren't able to see how you generate the dictionary, or what a sample output is. I would suggest you inspect element on your browser and see what is actually being inserted into the template javascript you're running. This information would be much more helpful to you (and your post) than these little snippets.

Comment: gotcha bud. Edited the question to reflect the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output:

```
var truck_dict = {'1301': [43.1220307, -78.9352247], '1302': [42.3107737, -77.2519131], '1304': [40.3809016, -74.5665863], '1305': [40.2453049, -74.5707928], '1303': [39.6435448, -75.9325289]};

for (var i in truck_dict) {
  console.log(i, truck_dict[i]);
}
```

output:

```
1301 [43.1220307, -78.9352247]
1302 [42.3107737, -77.2519131]
1303 [39.6435448, -75.9325289]
1304 [40.3809016, -74.5665863]
1305 [40.2453049, -74.5707928]
```

So, you need to log truck_dict, like:

```
var truck_dict = {{trucks | tojson}};

console.log(trucks);
console.log(truck_dict);
```

Comment: Thank you. Another issue was that, Mapbox GL uses the coordinates in reverse (lon, lat). That combined with your answer solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index a dictionary.Using `truck_dict[I]` doesn't work here because your indices are not numbers (not possible in js anyway).

You need to access dictionary elements with their keys (ex. `truck_dict['1301']` or `truck_dict.1301`) **NOT** indexes. If you want to iterate over each key (which you can use to reference the value mapped to that key), use:

```
for(var key in truck_dict) {
  var value = truck_dict[key];
  // do what you need with value and key here
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. it is the same in python as well. However, I think the error most likely has to do with how the dictionary is getting passed to js script. I implemented the code you provided but the key value pairs are not being parsed properly.

Comment: post what the generated js code looks like after the template has been rendered